# How to use single loop to obtain the given sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use just 1 loop in python to obtain the sequence like  (likes counter in second  and miliseconds)

```
0 0.033 0.066 0.1 0.133 0.166 0.2....
```

Currently, I have to use two loops to obtain it as follows

```
miliseconds =[0 0.033 0.066 0.1 0.133 0.166 0.2 0.233 0.266 0.3 0.333 0.366 0.4 0.433 0.466 0.5 0.533 0.566 0.6 0.633 0.666 0.7 0.733 0.766 0.8 0.833 0.866 0.9 0.933 0.966 1]
for second in range(100):
   for milisecond_ in miliseconds:
       print (second + milisecond_)
```

Comment: 0.033 milliseconds is 33 microseconds. Deal with integers as much as possible when programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mathematics:

```
# You can change second to '100'
second = 3
for i in range((30 * second)+1):
    print(round(i/30, 4))
    
    # If you want to get full precision -> uncomment below line
    # print(i/30)
```

Output:

```
0.0
0.0333
0.0667
0.1
0.1333
0.1667
0.2
0.2333
...
2.7333
2.7667
2.8
2.8333
2.8667
2.9
2.9333
2.9667
3.0
```

Comment: A `round(i, 4)` could be nice with that

Comment: @azro rounding wouldn't produce the exact numbers given in the question.  Better to leave them with full precision or use a custom truncation function.

Comment: Great solution. However if I just want to print number like x.033 x.066 x.1 where x is second instead of x.0333 x.0667 x.1. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: @MoonLee, maybe change `print(round(i/30, 4))` -> `print(round(i/30, 3))`. Are you wanting this?

Comment: Round 3 will gives 0.067 instead of 0.066

Comment: @MoonLee, Try this: `print(str(round(i/30, 4))[:-1])`